# Statically linking -lobc on GCC 4.6.x

Tags: objective-c, gcc

My problem is occurring using `MinGW32-w64` with `GCC 4.6.1`

With older versions of `GCC`, the `ObjC` runtime library was essentially rotten on the vine; it was often suggested that the shared library be trashed and to only link with the static library. The library itself only existed as a singular version, `libobjc.a`.

Starting with `GCC 4.6`, we recieved the all new `ObjC` runtime library that supports 2.0 features and all that other good stuff. It also introduced both 64 and 32 bit versions of the shared library (`libobjc_64-3.dll`, `libobjc-3.dll`), which you can actually link against without issue.

A quick look at the static library however reveals just a single file, `libobjc.a`, and is where my issue comes in: attempting to statically link to this library gives a reference undefined error to all runtime library functions.

Frankly, I don't know where to go from here and all my searches have turned up nothing useful. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the issue.

To statically link to the library, I tried both `-Wl,-static -lobjc` and when that didn't work, wen't for `-static -lobjc` to force the application to link everything as a static library. I received the same error in both cases.